# Rails application using chart.js optins

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, chart.js

I've got a rails application and I want to use char.js to generate some charts. That works fine.

But now I have to set up some option to configure chart options.

I want to customize the tooltip.

[image]

I want that the legend colors are the same like in the chart. How can I do this?

in case of this I have to do something like that:

```
    window.myLine = new Chart(weekdayChart).Line(weekdayChartData, {
        responsive: true,
        animation: true,

        legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"        });
```

problem here are the <%= because they are normaly rails outputs in the view ... how can I solve this problem?

Comment: If the file name ends with `.js` you are fine, if it ends with `.js.erb` you might want to rename it

Comment: Code is in a HTML.erb

Comment: That was the hint I needed I outsourced the code! thanks

Comment: Glad to help even if it's a side-effect. Added it as an answer, just for future references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file name ends with `.js` you are fine, no need to deal with `<%=`. However if the file ends with `.js.erb`, you are going to have problems.

Considering you don't need `ERB` in this case (you don't use it at all), I highly suggest renaming the file to end with `.js`